# Changing the XML attribute value in XML file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, javascript

This is my XML file.

```
<ops>
<emp>
    <name>asd</name>
    <ntid>123</ntid>
    <pwd>123</pwd>
    <score></score>
</emp>
<emp>
    <name>bvrtb</name>
    <ntid>1341</ntid>
    <pwd>1341</pwd>
    <score></score>
</emp>
</ops>
```

I have this script with which i'm able to change the pwd with a new password.

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('pwd');
x[i].setAttribute("pwd", document.getElementById("newpassword").value);
```

With this the value is getting changed but when i refresh the page again the same old value is loaded. How can i change this pwd value in the XML file..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you got the file from the web server right?. So you need to send it back up, and then it saves it, then next time you get it...

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is executed in a client browser and your code is operating on data "copy" returned by server. If you want to change XML you have to do it on server-side. Every time you are requesting XML it is loaded from server resources, not reachable by client JS code.

Comment: Is there any way i could then change the xml file

Comment: How do you fetch this XML file?

Comment: im fetching through javascript in a html

Comment: Ok, but I'm asking how do you load XML file, is it on web server (by URL of remote server)? Or is it file on your local machine?

Comment: it is in my local machine.. i have no problem in loading it from a server also.

Comment: So if you really want to edit file in browser, you can achieve it only using Microsoft dialect of ECMAScript called JScript. It can run only on IE. Example use: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ee7s9w2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0600__MS-JScript/FileSystemObjectOpentextFile.htm). There is also possibilty in using Google Chrome FileSystem API [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), but it your app will be sandboxed and you will have access only to your app's file (but I'm not sure about it)